# TypeScript: Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature

Tags: typescript

I have a function that instantiates a object with a given constructor, passing along any arguments.

```
function instantiate(ctor:Function):any {
    switch (arguments.length) {
        case 1:
            return new ctor();
        case 2:
            return new ctor(arguments[1]);
        case 3:
            return new ctor(arguments[1], arguments[2]);
        ...
        default:
            throw new Error('"instantiate" called with too many arguments.');
    }
}
```

It is used like this:

```
export class Thing {
    constructor() { ... }
}

var thing = instantiate(Thing);
```

This works, but the compiler complains about each `new ctor` instance, saying `Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.`. What type should `ctor` have?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'd write it this way (with generics as a bonus):

```
function instantiate<T>(ctor: { new(...args: any[]): T }): T {
```

Comment: me, too. Can you give a hint where someone can find some docs about.

Answer (score -1):

I also got this error when my type was wrapped in a module, and I was calling new on the module rather than the type. This Q&A helped me rule out some things, and then I came to the realization it was something quite silly after a long day of programming.

Comment: Was it an export versus export default problem?

Comment: I no longer work on this code base, and it was so long ago, that I cannot remember.  Sorry.  May I ask why you were asking?

Comment: Because I had a similar problem, and it was fixed because I was trying to use the exported class as if it was the default export eg import foo from "bar"; but foo was a regular export so I needed to import {foo} from "bar", or alternately change the export to default export (which is what I did)

Comment: That sounds vaguely familiar to my problem, except I did not change the default export, I changed the import side.